# How to finilize rxjs switchmap observable?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, rxjs-observables, switchmap

I have an observable in my angular 8  project, and subscribing in ngOnInit().

```js
     export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
       urlSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject();
       isLoading: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
       chartData: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);
       dataSubscription: Subscription;

       dataObservable: Observable<any> = this.urlSubject.pipe(
         switchMap((url: any) => this.httpClient.get<any[]>(url))
       )

       ngOnInit() {
         this.dataSubscription = this.dataObservable
          .pipe(tap(() => this.isLoading.next(true)))          
          .pipe(map((response: any) => response.result))      
          .subscribe((response: any) => this.chartData.next(response),
            () => this.isLoading.next(false),
            () => this.isLoading.next(false));

         this.urlSubject.next(this.data.settings.dataEndpoint)
      }
}
```

But complate method does not fire of subscribe.

I am subscribing to `chartData` that type is `BehaviourSubject`. So I do not subscribe to `urlSubject`. Because the url may change any time for searh or filter parameters.

I am using finilize but it does not work. I think this problem is about switchmap inner porecess. How can I finilize and set loading to false?

Comment: if `urlSubject` is a Subject then it never completes until you call `urlSubject.complete()`. So it's not the inner observable returned to `switchMap` that needs to be completed.

Comment: `urlSubject` is a Subject, I updated the post. So what can I do?

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do. Maybe in your situation you could just move `finalize()` into the inner observable. Like this `this.httpClient.get(url)).pipe(finalize(() => ...))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `finalize` on the `httpClient.get`. Subject and BehaviorSubject doesn't complete until you do it manually by calling `subject.complete()`. However Observable created by the `httpClient` completes after emitting api response and you need to use that.

For your example:

```js
dataObservable: Observable<any> = this.urlSubject.pipe(
  tap(() => this.isLoading.next(true)),
  switchMap((url: any) =>
    this.httpClient.get<any[]>(url).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.isLoading.next(false))
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above subjects never complete, unless you call subject.complete();

With that said, subjects are observables, you can always unsubscribe from them using `take(COUNT)` or `takeUntil` operators etc....

Comment: I am subscribing to `chartData` that type is BehaviourSubject. So I do not subscribe to `urlSubject`. Where to use `takeUntil `

Comment: `yoursubject.pipe(takeUntil(anotherSubject)).subscribe(...)`